# `parseValue` are not called for input parameter of a customised scalar type

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I define a schema like this:

```
const query = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
      quote: {
        type: queryType,
        args: {
          id: { type: QueryID }
        },
      },
    },
  });
const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query,
  });
```

The `QueryID` is a customised scalar type.

```
const QueryID = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'QueryID',
  description: 'query id field',
  serialize(dt) {
    // value sent to the client
    return dt;
  },
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    if (ast.kind === 'IntValue') {
      return Number(ast.value);
    }
    return null;
  },
  parseValue(v) {
    // value from the client
    return v;
  },
});
```

client query

```
query {
   quote(queryType: 1)
}
```

I found that the `parseValue` method is not called when clients send query to my server. I can see `parseLiteral` is called correctly. 
In most of the document I can find, they use `gql` to define schema and they need to put `scalar QueryID` in their schema definition. But in my case, I am using `GraphQLSchema` object for schema. Is this the root cause of that? If yes, what is the best way to make it works? I don't want to switch to `gql` format because I need to construct my schema at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serialize` is only called when sending the scalar back to the client in the response. The value it receives as a parameter is the value returned in the resolver (or if the resolver returned a Promise, the value the Promise resolved to).

`parseLiteral` is only called when parsing a *literal* value in a query. Literal values include strings (`"foo"`), numbers (`42`), booleans (`true`) and `null`. The value the method receives as a parameter is the AST representation of this literal value.

`parseValue` is only called when parsing a variable value in a query. In this case, the method receives as a parameter the relevant JSON value from the `variables` object submitted along with the query.

So, assuming a schema like this:

```
type Query {
  someField(someArg: CustomScalar): String
  someOtherField: CustomScalar
}
```

serialize:

```
query {
  someOtherField: CustomScalar
}
```

parseLiteral:

```
query {
  someField(someArg: "something")
}
```

parseValue:

```
query ($myVariable: CustomScalar) {
  someField(someArg: $myVariable)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case, I have an argument defined as `args: {
          id: { type: QueryID }
        }`, but the `parseValue` method is not triggered.

Comment: Again, this doesn't have anything to do with how you're defining the args on the server. Only one of the three methods will ever be called. Whether `parseValue` or `parseLiteral` is called depends on whether you are using a variable or not.

Comment: I do use the variable in the query function like: `quote(queryType: 1)`. The variable value is `1`. But the method `parseValue` is not called.

Comment: Yes, parseValue is for variables, parseLiteral is for literal values. `1` is a literal value

Comment: Oh I see. I mis-understood about literal value and variables. Thanks mate.